# how to use elementor plugin in webstorm

Tags: javascript, protractor, webstorm, elementor

I am new to protractor tool for automation test in javascript. I am using webstorm as IDE for writing and executing the test cases and I have installed the elementor plugin in it but unable to use it, when i am selecting the particular line of code and right clicking and click on "Test selected locator" - it is showing:

> error testing locator:connection refused:connect

Although I am connected to my network. Can someone help me in using this plugin in webstorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you have not started the selenium server:

```
$ webdriver-manager start
```

And the `elementor` itself:

```
$ elementor your_url_here
```

FYI: [How to launch `elementor`?](https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor#how-to-launch)

Comment: hello alecxe, i tried as advised above for the first time its neither executing nor giving the error but if i try again it is closing the browser and cmd prompt. i tried without duplicating and with duplicating.